# How do I display the actual input instead of option number?

Tags: java, string, random

I'm trying to get this to display the actual input instead of the option number.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int length;
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("How many options?"); //user input food options
       length = input.nextInt();

       String[] names = new String[length];
       for(int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++){
           System.out.println("Enter option #" + (counter+1) + ":");
           names[counter] = input.next();   
       }

       input.close();

       System.out.println("You are going to eat " + new Random().nextInt(names.length));
```

Comment: So what's the problem? You've stored your input, just print it back out.

Comment: Look at this line: `names[counter] = input.next();`. That's how you access an element of an array. Apply that to your final line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already generated a random number here:

```
new Random().nextInt(names.length)
```

You can use this random number to access an element in the `names` array.

```
int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(names.length);
String option = names[randomNumber]; // here is the important bit!
```

Now you can print `option` out!

```
System.out.println("You are going to eat " + option);
```